# date range logic computation (min current date)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, datepicker

Currently I have a mat date picker range. The logic is the min date on the calendar that the user can select is + 2 full days but exlude the counting of weekends for example

If today is 25(July 25, 2022 ) then the current date([min]="currentDate") should be 28 which is thursday July 28, 2022.

If today is 26(July 26, 2022 ) then the current date([min]="currentDate") should be 28 which is thursday July 29, 2022.

But if for example if its friday it should not include the count of weekends for example today is
29(July 29, 2022 ) then the current date([min]="currentDate")should be Wednesday  3(August 03, 2022 .

And same logic goes to every dates.

Any idea guys how would we make it possible with the calendar? Thanks.

#blitz

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byrmnt-setsza?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.html
```

#html

```
   <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input
    [min]="currentDate"
    [rangePicker]="picker"
  >
    <input matStartDate matInput placeholder="Start date" />
    <input matEndDate matInput placeholder="End date" />
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

#ts code

```
  export class DateRangePickerOverviewExample {
    currentDate = new Date();
  
    ngOnInit(): void { 
      this.currentDate = new Date(this.currentDate.setDate(this.currentDate.getDate() + 2));
    }
  
    // weekendsDatesFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    //   const day = d.getDay();
    //   /* Prevent Saturday and Sunday for select. */
    //   return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
    // };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getMinDate(date: any) {
    return dateCompare=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(x=>
             new Date(date.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000*x)))
             .filter(x=>x.getDay()!=6 && x.getDay()!=0)
             .find((x,i)=>i==1)
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xnawq5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** explained

The code create an array of 7 dates (each element in the array one day).

```
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(x=>
       new Date(date.getTime()+(24*60*60*1000*x)))
```

Transform the array [1,2,3,4,5..] in an array of dates, e.g. [2022-07-29,2022-07-30,2022-07-31,2022-08-01,2022-08-02...]

Then filter and only get the dates who are not sunday nor saturday.

```
             .filter(x=>x.getDay()!=6 && x.getDay()!=0)
```

the new array becomes like [2022-07-29,2022-08-01,2022-08-02,...]

Finally gets the element in position 2 (in the array the position 1 is the index 0, the position 2 is the index 1...)

```
             .find((x,i)=>i==1)
```

gets 2022-08-01

If we need one day not sunday or saturday we can change the "i==1" by "i==2".

Comment: Hi Sir , where is the part if your code where I can change instead of +2 I will use + 3

Comment: for example if its today is august 01, 2022 then current date should be thursday which is august 04, 2022

Comment: There is an issue with your answer Sir , if today is 29 (July 29, 2022) then the min date should be wednesday august 03 , 2022

Comment: @DiyaAgastya, Sorry for put a code without explain it (I just update the answer with it):  you can change the "i==1" by "i==2".

Answer (score 1):

To handle such date management, you are better of using a library like [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/weekday#docsNav). Then you can check if a given date is weekend, and easily add 1 or 2 days to the date.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

let weekday = require('dayjs/plugin/weekday')


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  currentDate;

  constructor(){
    dayjs.extend(weekday);
    this.currentDate = new Date(this.getDateTwoWeekDaysLater());
  }

  getDateTwoWeekDaysLater() {
    let plusTwoDate = dayjs().add(3, 'day').endOf('day');

    // 6 = sat, 0 = sun
    if (plusTwoDate.weekday() === 6) {
      plusTwoDate = plusTwoDate.add(2, 'day');
      console.log('loop');
    } else if (plusTwoDate.weekday() === 0) {
      plusTwoDate = plusTwoDate.add(1, 'day');
    }

    return plusTwoDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A');
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dayjs-q9xgec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Hi @Nehal , the thing is I wanna apply it to an angular material calendar , I have my sample stackblitz above Sir and I am using angular

Comment: My example is not stopping you from using angular. You can add dayjs library to your angular project and code it exactly the way I have in the answer, and whichever property holds the date, bind it to the mat calendar

Comment: I tried importing the lib but it does not work , do you have any alternative package that works well with angular?

Comment: My stackblitz demo is wtih Angular. But I have updated it with example of mat datepicker min date set to today + 2 week days.

Comment: Property 'weekday' does not exist on type 'Dayjs'.

Comment: Did you notice the line ‘ dayjs.extend(weekday);’ in the contructor and the declaration of weekend plugin at line 4?

Comment: If today is 27(July 27, 2022 ) then the current date([min]="currentDate") should be  1(August 01, 2022.)

Comment: Just need to increase the count from 2 to 3 in `let plusTwoDate = dayjs().add(3, 'day').endOf('day');`